# find element by xpath but only specified tags

Tags: html, python-3.x, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to find element by xpath currently I am using this.

```
title = self.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[starts-with(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'{search.lower().strip()}')]")
```

but its giving me any match in any of the tags, but I want the element of it matches only specified tags such as h1,h2,span etc.

I have tried doing this

```
title = self.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span|h1|h2|h3|h4|a[starts-with(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'{search.lower().strip()}')]")
```

but it doesnot work.

Comment: Can you share more details about what your code intend to do? Selecting either link or any header or `span` in Selenium is not what usually one want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//*[self::span or self::h1 or self::h2]
```

will select all `span`, `h1`, or `h2` elements in the document.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but I am kinda new to xpaths so will it be self.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[self::span or self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::a ][starts-with(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'{search.lower().strip()}')]")

Comment: Your second predicate will further filter the listed elements to those whose first text node's string value starts with the string returned by the given python expression.